# InsertedDate, set Default Value in DB or Set in application?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am writing a new application and I am in the design phase.  A few of the db tables require to have an `InsertedDate` field which will display when the record was inserted.

I am thinking of setting the `Default Value` to `GetDate()`

Is there an advantage to doing this in the application over setting the default value in the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think its better to set the Default Value to GetDate() in SQL Server, rather than in your application. You can use that to get an ordered table based on insertion. It looks like an overhead if you try to set it from the application. Unless you want to specify some particular date with the insert, which I believe kills the purpose of it.

Comment: I second that. That is the most common, faster, and very likely more accurate way.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need to manually INSERT a record into the database, you'll need to remember to set this field if you're setting the default value in your application to avoid NULL references.

Personally, I prefer to set default values in the database where possible, but others might have differing opinions on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in your application, **you can unit test it**.  In the projects I've been on, especially when using an ORM, we do all default operations in the code.

Answer (score 0):

When designing, I always put a lot of importance on separation of concern, which for me, in the context of "database functionality vs application functionality", boils down to the question: "Who owns the data?". I have always been of the opinion that my code owns my data - never the database. The database is simply the container for data. This is similar to saying that I own my clothes, rather than my dresser owning my clothes. My dresser performs an important function, making my clothes available in an organized fashion, but I am always the agent putting clothes in the dresser, and I am responsible for their organization.

I'm sure many will have a problem with this analogy, saying that modern databases are much more powerful than my dresser, but in my experience the more functionality I put in the database layer, the more confusing projects get and the more blurred the line between data and functionality (e.g. database stored procedures, etc). Admittedly, yours is a simple example of this concept, but once a precedent is set, anything goes.

Another thing I'd like to address is the ease-of-use factor. I reject the idea that because a particular implementation is convenient (such as avoiding nulls, different server times, etc.) then I should choose it. To me, choosing such implementations is equivalent to saying: "It's alright if my code doesn't work. I'll avoid using my code rather than fixing it and making it robust."

I'm sure there are many cases, perhaps at extreme scale or due to other business requirements, when database-layer functionality is not only warranted but necessary, but my experience tells me the more you can keep your functionality in your code, the cleaner, simpler, and more robust your application will be.